# HTML Different styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the two styles of html code written below.

```
return '<div id='suggestionId' class="autocomplete-suggestion">No Message Found</div>';
```

Vs

```
var autoCompleteSuggestion;
 autoCompleteSuggestion = $('<div/>').attr({id: 'suggestionId'}).addClass('suggestion').html('No Message Found');
return autoCompleteSuggestion;
```

Results are same, the below mentioned script what kind of scripting is it called. Would like to know more

Comment: The first has syntax error because of the single codes.

Second is more readable for programmers.

Comment: The first one is a syntax error.

Comment: More to the point... The first one (attempts to) return a string literal.  The second one uses jQuery functions to build an object and return that.  Are you just asking what jQuery is?

Answer (score 4):

The first one is hard-coded vanilla javascript. The second one uses the jQuery api to build the string.

Also, your first one uses quotes incorrectly. But it looks like that's not intentional.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your first script wont work because you use

```
 return '<div id='suggestionId' class="autocomplete-suggestion">No Message Found</div>'; //you should use id="suggestionId".
```

The first code is a javascript code returns a string which contains tags and attributes of a div.

the second code is written in JQuery and returns a string built by JQuery functions.

The result (if there is no syntax error) will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one of them is just straight HTML.

The first one is vanilla javascript. But should be written like this

```
return '<div id=' + suggestionId + ' class="autocomplete-suggestion">No Message Found</div>';
```

Otherwise `suggestionId` will throw an error and not render the id.

The second one is written using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), but can be modified to be just

```
return $('<div/>').attr({id: 'suggestionId'}).addClass('suggestion').html('No Message Found');
```

Both will render the same to the browser.